# Is there a way to calculate the value of B on a point P inside a current carrying loop which is at a distance of x from the centre?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The value of x isn't 0. If we take diameter AC on point P, let's say A is closer to P than C, then would P experience a magnetic force due to C.

Comment: Have you tried Biot-Savart law?

Comment: can you clarify the geometry? If you point P on the symmetry axis of the loop or off-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but the answer cannot be done in terms of simple functions and you must accept either a numerical answer or an infinite series.

I will assume from the statement of the problem that your loop is in the $xy$ plane at $z=0$, that the loop has radius $R$ and that you want the value of $\vec B$ at at point $P$ in the plane a distance $r<R$ from the axis.

It is clear that, without loss of generality, one can choose this point $P$ to be located at $\vec r_P= r\hat x$.  Let use $\vec r_s$ for a small piece of the loop, and that the current goes counterclockwise in the loop.  Write
\begin{align}
\vec r_s= R\cos\theta\hat x+ R\sin\theta \hat y
\end{align}

Then by Biot-Savart:
\begin{align}
d\vec B=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} I d\vec \ell \times \frac{\vec r_p-\vec r_s}{\vert r_p-\vec r_s\vert^3}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
d\vec \ell&= -R\sin\theta d\theta \hat x + R\cos\theta d\theta \hat y\, ,\\
\vec r_p-\vec r_s&= (r-R\cos\theta)\hat x - R\sin\theta \hat y\, ,\\
\vert \vec r_p-\vec r_s\vert&= \sqrt{r^2+R^2-2 r R\cos\theta}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
d\vec \ell \times \frac{\vec r_p-\vec r_s}{\vert r_p-\vec r_s\vert^3}
= \hat z \frac{R(R-r \cos\theta)d\theta}{(r^2-2 r R \cos (\theta )+R^2)^{3/2}}\, .
\end{align}
This then needs to be integrated of $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$.  The integral does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of simple functions.  To proceed numerically introduce the dimensionless ratio $\rho=r/R<1$ and reexpress
\begin{align}
d\vec \ell \times \frac{\vec r_p-\vec r_s}{\vert r_p-\vec r_s\vert^3}
=\frac{d\theta (1-\rho  \cos (\theta ))}{R \left(1-2 \rho  \cos
   (\theta )+\rho ^2\right)^{3/2}}\, .
\end{align}
For fixed $\rho$, i.e. fixed ratio of $r/R$, this can be solved numerically or
analytically by expanding the denominator in powers of $\rho$; in the latter case this is an infinite sum.  Anyways, suppose for instance that $\rho=1/\sqrt{2}$, then the integral gives $10.80/R$.  You can then finish the calculation by yourself